# Why my Xcode macOS app connects to an unknown remote server

Tags: scenekit, xcode11.4

a quick question for what is strange behavior in my opinion. 
I'm developing an app which, for the moment, is meant to run fully ***locally***, with no network access at all.
Well, since when I've introduced some 3d graphics I'm having this in the debugger log window (in light sky blue)

[image]

Please note that such (apparent?) CDN access was fully absent before the addition of a 3d scene.

Could someone tell me what Apple is asking to a CDN and, most important, how can I prevent such accesses that have not been explicitly authorized/configured by the end user?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this case "CDN" does not refer to a *Content Delivery Network*, but rather to Apple's CoreDisplay framework. The following command will show that these logs come from the framework:

```
strings /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/CoreDisplay | grep "client setup_"
```

Comment: Thank you, mnuages. You're right, but what's actually my App asking to this... huh? CoreDisplayNetwork? Does it mean that my PC must be connected to Apple's servers if I want to have 3D content in my App??? If for whatever reason my PC is offline, is my App dead?

Comment: This has nothing to do with *networks*, the "N" is for *Notification*. These are harmless logs and don't affect your app in any way.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. It may well be that N stands for Notification, nonetheless the log sounds like something network. It is stated: "Remote port" "Local port". Typical "network" language.